# how to delete all .svn hiden files from my project to do an update in svn repository

Tags: svn

Hi, I have a problem using SVN repository. When I try to update my project in SVN I'm getting the following error:

```
oomsys@oomsysmob-6:~/brundelre3$ svn st
svn: warning: '.' is not a working copy
oomsys@oomsysmob-6:~/brundelre3$ svn up
Skipped '.'
```

I tried the things which explained about this error previously from the following links:

Removing .svn files from all directories

http://bookmarks.honewatson.com/2008/06/06/find-and-remove-hidden-folders-svn-ubuntu-linux-command-line/

http://www.ubun2.com/question/348/how_remove_all_svn_folders_recursively

but nothing solves my problem. I want to remove all the hidden files from my project.

Thanks

Nirmala Sudhir

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all dot files in a folder using `find` and `rm`.

`find . -name ".*" -type f | xargs rm -v`

It searches for all dot files in the given folder, passed the results to `rm` which deletes it. It doesn't delete directories. When no files are found to delete, `rm` will return `rm: missing operand`.

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the instructions in the two links then you have already removed all the svn files.

That is the reason you cannot do an svn update now. The .svn folders within the source code directory contain all the data that is used by svn to determine what has been changed and where to get the updates from. They are needed by svn to update the files you have.

If you want to remove all hidden files and folders but keep the the svn data then you want something like-

```
find /path/to/workdir -name ".*" -not -name ".svn" -not -name "." | xargs rm -Riv
```

If you have made changes you want to keep then you need to put those source files to the side and checkout a new copy. You should then run diff between the two folders and merge in any changes you wish to keep. Then you will be back to a point of being able to use svn up as well as svn diff / svn ci etc.

If you haven't made changes then just delete all and do a new svn co